# jQuery Cycle pager function using existing thumbnails for navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, cycle, portfolio

I'm working on a portfolio site for my wife's lighting design business. The jQuery cycle plugin seems to provide the functionality I want, but even after reviewing the examples on Mike Alsup's site, I'm stumped. Really, I just don't have the background with JavaScript to pull this off myself.

I want to build a slideshow, controlled with a pager function, using thumbnails for navigation. The main slides and the thumbnails are totally different aspect ratios (to maintain the layout), so I can't use cycle to generate the thumbnails for me. The slides include an image and a caption. I'd like to preserve as much of the existing markup as possible.

Here is the slideshow content:

```
<div id="slideshow" />
        <div class="first">
            <img src="../_/img/projects/shootingstar-1.jpg" alt="" />
            <p class="credit">caption here</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="../_/img/projects/shootingstar-2.jpg" alt="" />
            <p class="credit">caption here</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="../_/img/projects/shootingstar-3.jpg" alt="" />
            <p class="credit">caption here</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="../_/img/projects/shootingstar-4.jpg" alt="" />
            <p class="credit">caption here</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="../_/img/projects/shootingstar-5.jpg" alt="" />
            <p class="credit">caption here</p>
        </div>
```

Here is the thumbnail/navigation content. I tried to use a consistent naming convention for the images:

```
<div id="slidenav">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="../_/img/projects/shootingstar-1t.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="../_/img/projects/shootingstar-2t.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="../_/img/projects/shootingstar-3t.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="../_/img/projects/shootingstar-4t.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="../_/img/projects/shootingstar-5t.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    </div>
```

And finally, my styling, in case that is helpful in some way:

```
#slidenav {display: block; float: right; width: 200px;}
#slidenav li {list-style: none; float: left;}
#slidenav li img {padding: 2px; border: 1px solid #999; margin: 0 0 8px 8px;}
#projectcopy {display: block; float: right; width: 220px;}
#projectcopy p {font-size: 12px; color: #666; line-height: 16px; margin: 0 10px 20px 16px; text-align: right;}
#projectcopy ul {list-style: none; margin: 0 10px 20px 16px;}
 #projectcopy ul li {font-size: 11px; color: #666; line-height: 14px;  text-align: right; margin-bottom: 10px;}
```

I have an example posted here:

http://pritchardlighting.com/nova/portfolio/sample-project.html

You can see that I currently just have a simple cycle set up on the slides. Please ignore the mess. Obviously, this is still in dev.

I would really appreciate any help. This has to be something that others have tried to do. I'm just having a hard time making my way through the examples I've seen so far. They all assume (rightly so) a baseline understanding of JS that I just don't possess.

Comment: Hi, I'm not quite sure how you want to do the slideshow. Do you want the main picture in the "slideshow" DIV to change whenever you HOVER over a thumbnail, or whenever you CLICK on a thumbnail? Presumablu from your description you don't want the picture to cycle on timer, like it is doing at the moment.

Comment: Hi Neil. I want the first slide to display when the page loads and then advance when a user clicks on any of the other thumbnails. I want the thumbnail of the active slide to take on a new class ("active" or something similar), so I can style it with a different border. And you're correct, I don't want the slides to cycle like I have it now. I just have that in place while I was doing some trouble shooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. remove all divs you have wrapped around your content to cycle (the child elements of div#slideshow. they prevent cycle from working as the script cycles everything within ONE div).
2. remove p.credit for the same reason. otherwise the script cycles it and you run into trouble if you have no matching thumbnail (see 3.)
3. make sure, the number of thumbnails {*t.jpg}  matches precisely the number of img in {div#slideshow}. thats the point that makes it work. mismatch leads to a non working script.
4. use exactly the jquery markup from the demo and replace {pager:  '#nav',} with {pager:  '#slidenav',}

if still not working check with firebug if the script loads. if yes, try first to make the cycle {div#slideshow} running before you move forward to the linked thumbnails.

Comment: Totff: Dude, I can't thank you enough. It works like a champ. I still need to do some IE testing, and I'll figure out what to do with the caption content later. Should be a simple fix. The working page is posted to the URL above. Seriously...thank you. This is huge.

Answer (score 3):

please refer [to this demo](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/pager3.html) to have your question answered:

Comment: Thanks, totoff. I've actually reviewed all the pager demos on malsup's site. I honestly can make heads or tails of them. I'm a total jQuery newb. I'd love to get this working, but I'm feeling like it's over my head.